How to pass source and destination table tables dynamically using variables ,expressions ,parameters in SSIS package
lest say
sourcetablenames--sourcetable_test1 and sourcetable_test2
destinationtablenames--destinationtable_test1 and destinationtable_test2
How create dynamic SSIS package,,so that we can transfer data from sourcetables in a loop dynamically
